# How to reverse the order of the image gallery in FancyBox?

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, photo-gallery

I'm editing a website that uses **Fancybox** as it's main photo gallery.

I was asked to add photos which I did by adding the photos to the main and thumbnail folders.

They show up fine except they **show up at the bottom of the page** after all the other pictures.  I want new photos uploaded to show up on top first so they are more visible.

Basically reverse the order of all the photos.  I've never used Fancybox so I'm just curious if this is easily possible  Looked around but couldn't find much.  Thanks.

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried so far

Comment: what is shown in the page has absolutely nothing to do with fancybox. fancybox will show them in the order you place them in the page or in your script when you create the gallery programmatically

Comment: Improved formatting, Also it's better if code is provided of what is tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of the list that you use to create the gallery. For instance you might have something that looks like:

```
<img src="./img1.jpg/>
<img src="./img2.jpg/>
<img src="./img3.jpg/>
<img src="./img4.jpg/>
```

Do this instead:

```
<img src="./img4.jpg/>
<img src="./img3.jpg/>
<img src="./img2.jpg/>
<img src="./img1.jpg/>
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter the order of the images but the order of the anchors that trigger the image in fancybox